# How to apply a function that outputs several column means for all the data frame objects in a list?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I know this must be a simple question, but I keep struggling with it.

I have this list of 124 data frames called "`kks`"

I want to input each one of the 124 data frames into the following function:

```
mytest_function <- function(df){
data.numcols <- df[, sapply(df, is.numeric)]
all.means <- apply(data.numcols, 2, mean)
all.means <- colMeans(data.numcols)
all.means
}
```

Essentially, I want the means of every column in all 124 data frames from a list of dataframes.

I've tried:

```
lapply(kks,mytest_function(df))
```

AND:

```
lapply(kks,mytest_function(kks))
```

and I can't figure it out. I keep getting error messages saying "`Error in colMeans(df) : 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions`"

What should I do from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could also use `purrr::map()` along with `dplyr::summarise_if()`, depending on the output format you desire. This would also eliminate the need for your custom function.

```r
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

kks %>%
  map(summarise_if, .predicate = is.numeric, .funs = mean)
```

Using `mtcars` as sample data.

```r
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

kks <- list(mtcars, mtcars, mtcars)

kks %>%
  map(summarise_if, .predicate = is.numeric, .funs = mean)

[[1]]
       mpg    cyl     disp       hp     drat      wt     qsec     vs      am   gear
1 20.09062 6.1875 230.7219 146.6875 3.596563 3.21725 17.84875 0.4375 0.40625 3.6875
    carb
1 2.8125

[[2]]
       mpg    cyl     disp       hp     drat      wt     qsec     vs      am   gear
1 20.09062 6.1875 230.7219 146.6875 3.596563 3.21725 17.84875 0.4375 0.40625 3.6875
    carb
1 2.8125

[[3]]
       mpg    cyl     disp       hp     drat      wt     qsec     vs      am   gear
1 20.09062 6.1875 230.7219 146.6875 3.596563 3.21725 17.84875 0.4375 0.40625 3.6875
    carb
1 2.8125
```

Comment: When I run the code, an error message comes back saying "Error in UseMethod("tbl_vars") : 
  no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "character" "

Comment: It's tough to answer that without a sample of your data. When I create a dummy object `kks` using the mtcars data it works correctly. I have updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

`apply` with margin 2 and `colMeans` are doing the same thing. You can use either one of them

```
mytest_function <- function(df){
   data.numcols <- df[, sapply(df, is.numeric)]
   colMeans(data.numcols, na.rm = TRUE)
}
```

and use `lapply`

```
output <- lapply(kks, mytest_function)
```

---

You can also use `summarise_if` from `dplyr` library

```
library(dplyr)

mytest_function <- function(df){
   df %>% summarise_if(is.numeric, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
}
```